# how to set image file path in app config file?

Tags: c#, application-settings

**I have a console application and it has a folder images in it.**

How can I set path in the app.config file similar to below:

~/images/logo.jpg

../images/logo.jpg

Comment: What seems to be a problem? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Use System.IO.Path.Combine method to combine a base path with a relative path like:

```
 System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, relativePath);
```

Environment.CurrentDirectory in the above line with whatever base path you want.

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking how to add those file names to the app.config?

if so...

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="image1" value="~/images/logo.jpg"/>
</appSettings>
```

This can be read by adding a reference to System.Configurations

And then calling `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["image1"]`;

You can access any value in the app.config using the Configuration manager.